# PHP block proxy

Tags: php, .htaccess, proxy

I'm currently creating a website and I'd like to block any kind of proxys.
I know that I can't block every proxy but I don't want that people with proxys visit my website. (It's for manipulation protection).

I already searched for a script and I've found this.

```
if (
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ||      
    ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == '') || 
    ($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'] != '')
) {
    die("Don't use proxies, please.");
}
```

But It would be much easier to write it in the .htaccess file. But I really don't know how.

Can anybody help?

Thank you
Mel

Comment: Do you realise that many people have no choice but to use the proxy provided by their ISP, and that people who would want to hack your site would probably use an undetectable proxy anyway?

Comment: Proxies also do not have to set any headers on outbound requests, those are voluntary, arbitrary, and spoofable. So if I want to do malicious things the first thing I'm going to do is turn off my proxy's outbound headers. You're mainly going to be blocking legitimate users.

Comment: it seems you need this http://serverfault.com/a/62370/321360